# pydrake is not available for installation anymore through google colab?

Tags: drake

I have been using a google colab template for iterative LQR that uses the Pydrake, however, it seems like the code repository is removed and I can't reinstall it on google Colab:

```
try:
    import pydrake
    import underactuated
except ImportError:
    !curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/master/scripts/setup/jupyter_setup.py > jupyter_setup.py
    from jupyter_setup import setup_underactuated
    setup_underactuated()

# Setup matplotlib backend (to notebook, if possible, or inline).  
from underactuated.jupyter import setup_matplotlib_backend
plt_is_interactive = setup_matplotlib_backend()
```

```
  File "/content/jupyter_setup.py", line 1
    404: Not Found
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried clicking this link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/master/scripts/setup/jupyter_setup.py, and the page is not found... everything was working fine yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.  You're correct... I updated it this morning, and don't have a good deprecation policy in place on that repo, and this setup script is two versions ago.  The path you want is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/master/setup/jupyter_setup.py
(remove the `script` from the directory).  But if you look at that file, you'll see that even that is pointing to an updated setup script which you might want to point to.

This is actually all good news... we are on the path to a much better solution.  You can now just `pip install drake` on colab (see the drake installation guide).  Once I land the `pip install underactuated` (probably in time for my Spring offering of the class), then all of that nasty setup will be gone.

Comment: Thank you professor

Comment: I replaced the link with the new one, but this error is returned this time: ```File "/content/jupyter_setup.py", line 1
    404: Not Found
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: The header at the top of the course note examples should work (I tested it when I made the change): https://colab.research.google.com/github/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/intro.ipynb

Comment: Thank you! I also wonder if there is a completed version of the iLQR colab notebook? I'm having some trouble with some functions in that notebook and it would be nice if I can reference a working notebook